# Kubernetes pod - image never pulled error

Tags: maven, kubernetes, fabric8, lagom

I'm trying to deploy my Lagom accessservices on Kubernetes.

To do that I tried to containerize my service using fabric8’s docker-maven-plugin.

So, I added the following plugin settings to the root project pom.xml to register the fabric8 Maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
        <images>
            <image>
                <name>%g/%a:%l</name>
                <build>
                    <from>openjdk:8-jre-alpine</from>
                    <tags>
                        <tag>latest</tag>
                        <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                    </tags>
                    <assembly>
                        <descriptorRef>artifact-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </assembly>
                </build>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

And then, I Added the following plugin settings on the pom.xml under the application’s module directory:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>false</skip>
        <images>
            <image>
                <build>
                    <entryPoint>
                        java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -cp '/maven/*' -Dhttp.address="$(eval "echo $ACCESSSERVICE_BIND_IP")" -Dhttp.port="$(eval "echo $ACCESSSERVICE_BIND_PORT")" -Dakka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname="$(eval "echo $AKKA_REMOTING_HOST")" -Dakka.remote.netty.tcp.bind-hostname="$(eval "echo $AKKA_REMOTING_BIND_HOST")" -Dakka.remote.netty.tcp.port="$(eval "echo $AKKA_REMOTING_PORT")" -Dakka.remote.netty.tcp.bind-port="$(eval "echo $AKKA_REMOTING_BIND_PORT")" $(IFS=','; I=0; for NODE in $AKKA_SEED_NODES; do echo "-Dakka.cluster.seed-nodes.$I=akka.tcp://accessservice@$NODE"; I=$(expr $I + 1); done) play.core.server.ProdServerStart
                    </entryPoint>
                </build>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After that, I build my project using:

```
eval $(minikube docker-env) 
clean package docker:build
```

And I think that it was succeeded because when I executed "docker images", I had:

[image]

But my problem is when I tried to deploy my services, I got this error:

> Container image is not present with pull policy of NeverError syncing
>   pod
>   [image]

Do you have any explication for that? please.

*** Edit 1 ****

> kubectl describe po accessservice-0
>   [image]

Comment: please post output of: `kubectl describe po accessservice-0`

Comment: Is the docker image public? Seems like your pods are unable to pull it.

Comment: Yeah @vivekyad4v but he built the image in his minikube node.

Comment: I guess you're missing `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent` in your podSpec

Comment: @whites11 - Yeah, agree. I guess `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent` should do since it's trying to pull the image everytime even if it's already present.

Comment: I edit the question to post the output of: kubectl describe po accessservice-0. What do you mean by public image ? And how can I check if  imagePullPolicy is present or not ??

Comment: How did you deploy your application?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use other `imagePullPolicy` different than `Never`, otherwise kubernetes will never try to download the image for your container. [You can choose](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images) between Always or IfNotPresent, which will download the image only if it's not already downloaded. For example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  containers:
    - name: my-app
      image: my-app-image
      imagePullPolicy: Always
```